# Check strings on Mail.Body or Subject of reply mail and add recipients

Tags: vba, email, outlook

When my managers send an email to do work,
then after I finish this work and press (reply or ReplyAll) and send that email,
I found I forgot to add recipients (not included on the original mail).

I do not add these recipients to all my replies, only if the `mail.Body` or `Subject` contain specific words. e.g “Test” or “vip”.

I added these recipients to a contact group with name e,g “5-Task Team”.

I need VBA to:

**1**- Check strings on the replied mail (after I click reply/All on the ribbon or choose it from context menu),
**2**- if it contains specific words, show a Message Box to remind me,
**3**- then add my contact group to the recipients (**To** Field)

I will send the mail manually.

The below code works only with showing the message box.
It fails to add the recipients (even if hard-coded), without any error raised.

This sub is found in a separate module:

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Check_Body_before_sendReply()
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)

    Debug.Print olMail.Body

    If olMail.Body Like "*Test*" Or olMail.Body Like "*VIP*" Then
        MsgBox "Required strings are found"
        olMail.Recipients.Add ("Test@Test.net")  ‘hardcoded because I do not know how to add a contact group
    Else
         MsgBox "Not Found"  'just for testing purpose
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is in ThisOutlookSession (no other code):

```vb
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private WithEvents myAttExp As Explorer
Private WithEvents myAttOriginatorMail As MailItem
Dim WithEvents oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myAttExp = ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub myAttOriginatorMail_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
     Check_Body_before_sendReply
End Sub

Private Sub myAttOriginatorMail_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Check_Body_before_sendReply
End Sub

Private Sub myAttExp_SelectionChange()
    On Error Resume Next
    If TypeOf myAttExp.Selection.Item(1) Is MailItem Then
        Set myAttOriginatorMail = myAttExp.Selection.Item(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, use `olMail.Recipients.Add ("groupName")`  'of course, your contacts group real name, followed by `olMail.Recipients.ResolveAll`...

Comment: I removed the lines of `MsgBoxs`, and tried your suggestion , the result it is sometimes works with `ReplyAll` and never works with `Reply` on the same email and the same conditions

Comment: It shouldn't be related to replay way... Is the sender you reply to in the respective group? I am trying to imagine if sending the message twice could be the reason of Outlook hesitations. I tested the code with `Reply` and worked all the time. Try inserting a second identic line: `olMail.Recipients.ResolveAll`. It looks being a matter of no resolving the involved recipients. But, in that cases when it does not work, does it write the group name? I suppose, yes. If so, is it underlined suggesting in this way that it is resolved? Or it is a simple string. What right click context menu shows?

Comment: @FaneDuru , I found out that `”contact group”` is added to the original mail window itself !! , this is very strange as this field in not editable by outlook, even if select `Edit Message` from Action menu on the ribbon.
I think the cause of this problem in this line `Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)`

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry...  What do you mean by "is added to the original mail window itself"? Isn't it added by the code you show, adapted as I suggested above? `Set olMail = Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)` has nothing to do with adding anything. It just sets an object **without doing anything with it** (in this stage of setting).

Comment: @FaneDuru , I have updated my question with new pictures to clarify the problem and the result after the event codes have been triggered

Comment: There are some mistakes in your code, which can be corrected (I think), but i asked above **Is the sender you reply to in the respective group?** The same for people in CC, if you choose `ReplyAll`. I think, I can show you how to proceed in order to add the (resolved) mail group where it is necessary, but **if the existing recipients also belong to the added group they will receive two such mail**. Do you want a solution not taking care of this aspect (which is *much more complicated*...)?

Comment: @FaneDuru , the sender is not on (the respective group). If any recipient has been added two times **on To Field** ,then he will receive only a single email and not twice,
The recipient will receive the mail two or even three times if his name/address is found on the fields of (To..,CC..,Bcc) on the same time, If this happens I think it needs a separate question

Comment: You answered a little to late... Please, check the answer I posted and send some feedback. I could see a second (blurred) account in the received mail. Which (I thought) it  may be part of the group. Anyhow, it looked interesting to play with such a solution. I do not need it but who knows, in the future maybe I will...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `Response` not `ActiveExplorer().Selection(1)`.

```vb
Private Sub myAttOriginatorMail_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
     
     Debug.Print Response.Body

    If Response.Body Like "*Test*" Or Response.Body Like "*VIP*" Then
       MsgBox "Required strings are found"
       Response.Recipients.Add ("Test@Test.net")
    Else
       MsgBox "Not Found"  'just for testing purpose
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next adapted solution. Your way added the group to the selected mail...

1.Use the next adapted sub (which adds the mail group, but remove the recipients which already exist in the respective group(:

```
Sub Check_Body_before_sendReply(sender As Outlook.MailItem, grName As String)
  Dim arrAddr, rec As Outlook.Recipients, i As Long, El
  
  Set rec = sender.Recipients

  'extract the group recipients in an array
  arrAddr = GetGroupMailMembers(grName)
  
  'remove te recipients existing in group, too:
  'remove te recipients existing in group, too:
    For Each El In arrAddr
        For i = rec.count To 1 Step -1
            If El = rec.Item(i) Then rec.Remove i: Exit For
        Next i
    Next El
  sender.Recipients.Add (grName)
  sender.Recipients.ResolveAll
End Sub

Function GetGroupMailMembers(grName As String) As Variant
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application, objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder, objList As Outlook.DistListItem
    Dim objMember As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim arr, i As Long
   
    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    Set objList = objFolder.Items(grName)
   
    ReDim arr(1 To objList.MemberCount)
    For i = 1 To objList.MemberCount
        arr(i) = objList.GetMember(i).Address
    Next

    GetGroupMailMembers = arr
End Function
```

Please, use your way to identify the mails suitable for adding the group. I mean `If olMail.Body Like "*Test*" Or olMail.Body Like "*VIP*" Then`...

1. Adapt the Reply event in this way:

```
Private Sub myAttOriginatorMail_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Check_Body_before_sendReply Response, "yourGroupName"
End Sub
```

Do the same with `ReplyAll` event and play with it.

Take care to initialize `myAttExp`...

Comment: I tried your latest update and it works (showing the message box and add the respective group)  and up-voted.
But for Function `GetGroupMailMembers` , It did not work as it should, it did not remove the recipients which already exist in the respective group.
Anyhow, Please approve me to use it (as a trial) when I post a new question regarding this great idea.
Also please accept my apology as I accepted the other answer by “niton”.

Comment: I am on the road for the next 10 - 11 hours...

Comment: @Soma Only now I reached my hotel. 1. You know how much I care about reputation points, I mean, I don't care at all! 2. I would like to remind you that you asked for the next issue: **Add my contact group to the recipients (To Field)** and I supplied a solution in my initial comment. 3. After that you raise the issue of adding the (resolved *only sometimes*) in the initial mail. I commented saying **I can show you how to proceed in order to add the (resolved) mail group where it is necessary**. I already answered one of your questions adding attachments to the `Replay` code, using `response`.

Comment: @Soma 4. You said "Function `GetGroupMailMembers` does not work", which is not true. Firstly this function only **returns the addresses inside the respective group**. The elimination of the existing ones is done inside `Check_Body_before_sendReply`, which I tested today for `ReplyAll`, too and it works exactlh as it should. I only inversed the two iterations (not time to test the initial code), even if it should work as it used to be, too. 5. If you accept a connection I will be able to tell you what's happening in your installation. Of course, **only one group should be involved**...